# jQuery: Get range of div repeatable classes

Tags: jquery

I've got a basic idea for a default html table, which can have parent and child rows. HTML will look like this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="parent row">
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child row">
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child row">
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent row">
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child row">
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child row">
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

There is could be any number of "row" between collapsable "parent" and "child" rows. Point is, how can I get range of child rows of needed parent row, to operate with them correctly?

JSFiddle (if necessary): http://jsfiddle.net/DcQ8P/

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't get your point. What's your need?

Comment: @BeNdErR OP wants to create a expandable/collapsible rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suddenly this idea hit my mind, Go with this code,

```
$('tr.parent.row').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.row:not(.child)').toggle();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DcQ8P/1/)

**Note** : Use this code, but don't forget to have a look at the documentation of all the functionality used with this code.